# xUnit and moq with Unit of work and generic repository pattern in web api c#

Tags: generics, asp.net-web-api, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, xunit.net

I'm working a .net 6 and entity framework 6. Currently working in xUnit moq , so for post method need example code

I have Unit of work and Generic repositoy pattern in my web api c# project with entityframework.

Post method example need for xUnit testing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.